# Consulta MYSQL máximo valor

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tabla en la cual se van ingresando datos "medidas". 
Lo que requiero hacer es seleccionar el máximo valor promedio (prom) cuando el fuego sea igual a BN01. Actualmente realizo la consulta pero el fuego BN01 no tiene el máximo **id** sino que lo tiene el fuego BN02, los datos se van repitiendo ya que tengo que llevar el histórico de las medidas.

```
select id, interno, fuego, prom from prof where fuego='bn01' and id=(select max(id) from prof)
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso es fácil de solventar con la buena aplicación de la función `MAX` combinado con `group by` en SQL:

```
select MAX(prom)
from prof 
where fuego='bn01' 
group by fuego
```

Esto te devolverá el valor máximo de `prom` de la tabla `prof` dónde `fuego='bn01'`

Comment: Miquel, muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero esto ya lo había probado y me resulto tal cual lo planteas. El problema es que BN01, tiene 10 registros cada uno con su **id** autoincrementable, dado que se trata de una pieza de vehiculo que se va desgastando y cuando llega a un minimo valor, se reemplaza, entonces, el prom (promedio) va descendiendo, nace en 20mm hasta que se recambia en (4mm) y vuelve a tener 20 mm (mm = milimetros), con el maximo id obtengo el valor mas actualizado.

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución para obtener el promedio del máximo id.

La consulta me quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
select id, interno, prom 
from prof 
where 
    fuego="bn01" 
    and id = (
              select MAX(id) 
              from prof 
              where fuego="bn01"
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Queda mejor así:

```
SELECT * FROM prof WHERE fuego="bn01" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Bienvenido Dario. debes mejorar tu respuesta, revisa [answer]. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!